# Fetch Customer Dashboard Order URL

Tags: orders, customer, url

How can I fetch Order URL on frontend just like its done in `Customer Account dashboard > My Orders` ?

The code written in `history.phtml` file for `Order URL` is as under:

```
<span class="nobr"><a href="<?php echo $this->getViewUrl($_order) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Order') ?></a>
```

How can I call the function `getVIewUrl()` and pass my order_id to fetch the Order URL ?

I do not want to use `BaseUrl()` and then append `sales/order/view/order/id/$orderId`.

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
Mage::getUrl('sales/order/view', array('order_id'=>$orderId));
```

Comment: Are there any chances of me using `getViewUrl()` function here ?

Comment: Don't use `getViewUrl` unless you are in the same block. That method works only in that specific block. If you try to instantiate the block in an other page and use `getViewUrl` you might end up with strange results. I think what I suggested is the safest way to go.